# Java Miglayout gap push does not work as desired

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I want to achieve a layout like in this sample using MiG Layout. So the last JButton is located at the bottom of the JFrame.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
         mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
         mainFrame.pack();
         mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        this.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[grow, fill]", "[][][]push[]"));
        this.add(new JButton("Test1"), "wrap");
        this.add(new JButton("Test2"), "wrap");
        this.add(new JButton("Test..."), "wrap");
        this.add(new JButton("TestBottom"), "");
    }
}
```

My Problem is that the number of JButtons I want to add is variable, so I can not use the row definition in MiG Layout, so I tried this code (and several derivations)

```
public MainFrame() {
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug", "[grow, fill]", ""));
    this.add(new JButton("Test1"), "wrap");
    this.add(new JButton("Test2"), "wrap");
    this.add(new JButton("Test..."), "wrap");
    this.add(new JButton("TestBottom"), "gaptop push");
}
```

But unfortunately this does not work as desired.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this looks like what you want.  (kudos for your working example)

```
public MainFrame() {
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug, filly", "[grow, fill]", ""));
    this.add(new JButton("Test1"), "wrap");
    this.add(new JButton("Test2"), "wrap");
    this.add(new JButton("Test..."), "wrap");
    this.add(new JButton("TestBottom"), "push, bottom");
}
```

I find "fill" in the first param to MigLayout() to be useful in many situations (or "filly", "fillx").  Your gaptop was giving a 0px gap I think.